# Add text from div to URL onclick

Tags: javascript, text-to-speech

I'm trying to have this API to read the text within my article div when a button is pressed.

http://tts-api.com/

Any help appreciated..

Comment: So grab the text in your article div and append it to the url given in the example like: `http://tts-api.com/tts.mp3?q=hello+world`

Comment: Yes. But when a button is pressed the text within a div is added to the URL with a prefix above. not manually hardcode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/wn2dzv4w/

use
`var url="http://tts-api.com/tts.mp3?q=";` and append the div text to the link

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible instead of create a link to file, it directly popup and play or play in background? Thanks

Comment: use `window.open(resultUrl,'_blank')` to open that link in a new tab